# .net 4.5 WCF Automatic Response Decompression

Tags: .net, web-services, wcf, http, iis

This is the environment:

> - .net 4.5 / IIS7 (Win 2008 R2 Enterprise)
> - WCF service
> - .net client (UnitTest) is 4.5 on windows 8.1 (textmessage_encoding http-text-xml-soap-utf8)
> - SOAPUI 5
> - C#

.net client calls wcf service and (automatically by default) sets Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
But I always gets the text/xml response. While when I use SOAPUI and sets Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate then I get back gzip-ed (compressed) response.

> Q1) Why dont I get compressed response for .net client?
>
> Q2) And in .net4.5 chain - who/which component does the decompression
> of Response stream?

I know response compression is automatically done by IIS for iis hosted wcf service by enabling IIS dynamic http compression - which is the case I have done.

FYI: I check this using Wireshark

REF: [MSDN-Choosing a Message Encoder](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa751889(v=vs.110).aspx)